# Rotate the camera around an object using the arrow keys in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspectivecamera

Say I have a big cube with some objects on each of the faces (a bit like the google maps cube http://www.playmapscube.com/). I would like to be able to use the arrow keys to rotate the camera **around** the cube, instead of rotating all the objects individually.

So the left arrow will move the camera to the left, thus the cube would be turning right, and so on.

I've looked all over and didn't find anything about doing it with the keyboard.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hope you're not just copy-pasting stuff blindly...

Comment: I've tried to increment the X and Y positions of the camera (for left/right) and then updating the camera using `camera.lookAt(scene.position)` but that increased the distance of the camera away from the center of the scene... Is there a special method that I should be useing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, I am assuming this is just a math question.

Use the arrow keys to change the value of a variable `theta`, then in your render loop do something like this:

```
camera.position.x = 15 * Math.cos( theta );
camera.position.y = 10;
camera.position.z = 15 * Math.sin( theta );

camera.lookAt( scene.position );
```

Comment: That works great for turning left and right. How would I go about turning it up and down from the current position?

Comment: Come on, dude, you can figure that out. :-) Try spherical coordinates.

Comment: Ok, I've go this going.
`camera.position.y = 500 * Math.sin(theta);
camera.position.x = 500 * Math.cos(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
camera.position.z = 500 * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi);`

However when the camera reaches the very top or very bottom, it starts going back the other way..?

Comment: Sure enough. You have to stay away from the poles.

Comment: So is there no way to enable rotation up and down infinitely?

Comment: Use cylindrical coordinates, instead.

Comment: As you've probably guessed my 3D math isn't great, so I've tried converting my spherical coordinates to cylindrical but had no luck.

Comment: Use the formula in my answer, and use the up and down arrows to control the y-position; left and right arrows to control theta.

Comment: I've tried that but all that does is move away from the center of the scene. Can you show me in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXms8/)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18530/discussion-between-westlangley-and-eugene)

Comment: One final idea is to make the camera a child of a parent object, and the parent a child of a grandparent object. The gp only rotates on y and the parent only rotates on x. It's pretty cool: http://jsfiddle.net/HXms8/4/.

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution there! There are a few quirks, such as if you rotate the Y axis down and turn left, the cube will be turning right. But at least it can rotate up/down left/right all the way perfectly.